# CPT custom archive template does not get loaded

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, slug, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom content type called `events` that I register using the following function:

```
add_action('init', 'events_post_init');

function events_post_init() {
   register_post_type( 'events',
      array(
         'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Events',
            'singular_name' => 'Event',
            'add_new' => 'Create new',
            'add_new_item' => 'Create new event',
            'all_items' => 'All events',
            'view_item' => 'View event',
            'search_items' => 'Search events',
            'not_found' => 'No events found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No events found in trash',
            'menu_name' => 'Events',
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            array('slug' => 'events')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'editor', 'title', 'excerpt'),
    )
  );
}
```

Now I would like to add a page that will be used to display an archive of events when I'm visiting `/events/`, so I have created a new template named `page-events.php` and then added a new page called `Event Archive` with a slug equal to `events` and under `Page Attribute` I have choose the new template I just created.
The thing is that the template is not being used when I go to the specified url. However if I remove the call to `register_post_type()` then it gets loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `has_archive` to `false` in your arguments when registering your post type, flush your permalinks and you should be goog to go.

### EDIT

> **`has_archive`**
>
> (boolean or string) (optional) Enables post type archives. Will use `$post_type` as archive slug by default.
>
> Default: false

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved everything. One more reason to **really** read the documentation =) +1

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out. Enjoy :-)